# Cardinality of an algebra

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, lebesgue-measure, descriptive-set-theory

Suppose that $B$ is the Boolean algebra of all Lebesgue measurable sets in $I=[0,1]$ modulo Null sets.

> I am asking
>
> (1) What will be the cardinality of $B$. Does it have to be $|B|=\mathfrak c$.
>
> (2) Is there any $b\in B$ which is not Borel set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cardinality is $\mathfrak c$: First of all, it is at least $\mathfrak c$, as the sets $(0,x)$ are all inequivalent for different values of $x\in[0,1]$. Second, Lebesgue measure is regular, so any measurable set contains a $\sigma$-compact subset of the same measure, and is contained in a $G_\delta$ superset of the same measure. This shows that each equivalence class has a Borel representative. But there are only $\mathfrak c$ Borel sets.

Comment: thanks for the answer. As I understand that there is no Lebesgue measurable set of positive measure that is not Borel. Am I correct?

Comment: Not quite. A simple counterexample is to take a non-Borel subset of $[0,1]$ of measure $0$ (which exists, since any subset of the Cantor set has measure $0$), and consider its union with the interval $[1,2]$. What is true is that any measurable set is the union of a Borel set and a (not necessarily Borel) measure zero set.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Yes given $X$ Lebesgue measurable take the intersection of a countable sequence of open sets  $O_n  \supseteq X$ such that $m(O_n) \leq m(X) + \frac{1}{n}$. Then 
$m(\bigcap O_n-X)=0$ and $X\equiv \bigcap O_n$ in $B$. This means that any equivalence class in 
$B$ contains a $G_{\delta}$ set.

Comment: You want to consider the intersection of the open sets $O_n$, not the union, right?  And in any case I don't think you want to assert that it is _equal_ to $X$.

Comment: I think it reads better now.

Comment: One more thing: I think you want to say $m(\bigcap O_n - X) = 0$ and not the other way around.  Of course what you wrote is also correct, but trivial.